# Thickness of mesh important for successful deforms?

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I’m currently having problems with deforming my mesh with the arms of my armature. I was wondering if the thickness/length of the mesh can contribute to a successful deformation with weight paints? My character only has simple cylindrical arms, with the tip being the hand. They’re not exactly long/thick with an elbow either. Will this contribute to my current struggles?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: hard to say without screenshots or without the file itself...

Comment: Please clarify this question by showing your work.  The question as currently written is vague.

Comment: Updated original post. The arms of my character are small and the way they deform is weird.